# Unity Collab says "Cannot get revision from server"

Tags: unity-game-engine, collaboration

I tried setting up collab for my unity project but when hovering over the collab icon in the top left it says

> Cannot get revision from server.

[image]

In the console I get the following Error messages:

> [Collab] DepricationMiddleware::ServiceReadOnlyError: Collab service
> is deprecated, only read operations are allowed.

> Assertion failed on expression: 'm_ChannelAccessLeaseEndTime > 0.0'.

What causes this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity collab services has been deprecated and will no longer be supported, your project will get archived soon, you will have to migrate to Plastic SCM.

Here's how you can upgrade from [Unity Collab to Plastic SCM](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlasticSCMUpgradeCollab.html).

Comment: What if you just started using Unity?
I clicked collab & publish and now every time I open the project I get that error message over and over again in the console. When I attempt to migrate, Plastic SCM states I have no projects to migrate, because I never published to collab.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a new Unity Project and encountering the error without a reason, then by deleting the Unity Collaborate Package in **Package Manager** the error is solved.

- After removing it, make sure to **Restart** the Project.

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to [Alessandro Crimaldi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73098406/revisions) :

Whether it is an existing Unity Project or new one, here's a solution:

1. In Unity Editor: **Window -> Package Manager -> Collaborate -> Remove**
   (Package Manager might be fetching/refreshing packages and takes forever, click refresh list and then close the Package Manager then re-open it)
2. Then: **Edit -> Project Settings -> Services -> Collaborate -> Turn it OFF**
   (Appearing issues due to after removing collaborate from package manager it is still enabled on services, I had to double click to turn it off from services tab in project settings)
3. Finally: **Restart the project**